# Approximating distributions in expectation propagation

Tags: bayesian, inference, approximation

Can the approximating distributions for various factors in Expectation propagation be different distributions but still from the exponential family. For example, I have the following posterior form:

$$
p(w, \lambda, \phi) = p(\phi)p(\lambda)p(w|\lambda) \prod_{i}p(y_{i}|w, \phi, \lambda)
$$

So, I need to approximate each of these factors. My question is can, for example, $p(\phi)$ be  approximated as a gamma distribution and $p(w|\lambda)$ be a multivariate Gaussian and $p(\lambda)$ be some thing else from the exponential family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use different exponential families to approximate the marginal for different variables. You only need all messages into a variable to have the same type, so that they can be multiplied together to get the marginal.  In your example, $p(w|\lambda)$ (call it factor $a$) can be approximated by the two messages $m_{a \rightarrow w}(w) m_{a \rightarrow \lambda}(\lambda)$ while $p(\lambda)$ (call it factor $b$) is approximated by the single message $m_{b \rightarrow \lambda}(\lambda)$.  You need $m_{a \rightarrow \lambda}(\lambda)$ to have the same type as $m_{b \rightarrow \lambda}(\lambda)$ so that they can be multiplied together to get the approximate marginal for $\lambda$.